# Using If Else statements in addition to sets using Python

Tags: python

I have to create a fortune teller for school. I want the user to input a number between 1-9. But i also want to give an error message if they put in a different number. I'm using a set containing my numbers, but I can't call it in my if statements.

```
fortune_num = set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
user_num = input(f'Pick a number and find your fortune! Choose a number from 1 to 9 and hit enter: ')
print()
if user_num == fortune_num:
    print(user_num)
else:
    print('Error')
```

Comment: Why use a set at all? `1 <= x <= 9` or `x in range(1, 10)` would do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the keyword `in` to check set membership, also cast `input` into `int`:

```py
fortune_num = set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
user_num = input(f'Pick a number and find your fortune! 
\nChoose a number from 1 to 9 and hit enter: ')
print()
if int(user_num) in fortune_num: #this would throw an error if input is not int
    print(user_num)
else:
    print('Error')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code,

```
fortune_num = list(range(1,10))
user_num = input(f'Pick a number and find your fortune!\nChoose a number from 1 to 9 and hit enter: ')

if int(user_num) in fortune_num:
  print(user_num)
else:
  raise ValueError("You entered a wrong input!")
```

This would raise an actual Python error if the input is wrong.

If you want to give the user another chances to enter a correct input use this,

```
fortune_num = list(range(1,10))

while True:
  try:
    user_num = int(input(f'Pick a number and find your fortune!\nChoose a number from 1 to 9 and hit enter: '))
    if user_num in fortune_num:
      print(user_num)
      break
    else:
      raise ValueError

  except:
    print("\nYou entered a wrong input. Please enter a valid number!")
```

Change the code as per your needs but this would do work as the perfect foundation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `input` takes user input as a string. So even if they enter `1`, that won't match your set, because your set is of `int`, and their input is the *string* `'1'`, not the integer `1`. Also, there's no need to use a set. A `range` object is easier to generate, and since it contains multiple numbers, the variable name should be plural. You also don't have your indentation correct. I don't see what the `f` in the input function is doing, and if you want a multi-line string, you need triple quotes. Also, if you have a carriage return in your string, putting `\n` in the string gives you two line breaks; I'm not sure that's intended. So one way of doing this is:

```
fortune_nums = [str(num) for num in range(1,10)]
user_num = input('''Pick a number and find your fortune!
Choose a number from 1 to 9 and hit enter: \n''')
print()
if user_num in fortune_nums:
    print(user_num)
else:
    print('Error')
```

If you want to get fancier, you can keep your `fortune_nums` as int, then do a try-except on converting the input to int, catching the invalid literal error:

```
fortune_nums = range(1,10)
user_num = input('''Pick a number and find your fortune!
Choose a number from 1 to 9 and hit enter: \n''')
print()
try:
    if(int(user_num) in fortune_nums):
        print(user_num)
except ValueError:
    print("That's not a valid integer!")
```

Answer (score -1):

1. if user_num == fortune_num: // instead of this; you can use keyword in int(user_num) in fortune_num:,
2. Also your print statement must be indented, otherwise you might get indentation error.